How to solve the LTspice error "Questionable use of curly braces in xxx."?
When I set up the following circuit, I ran into a question about the use of braces({})

The following are error messages：

Why can't the first V be recognized by LTspice, or is something else wrong?

please copy the error  message and paste into your post ... do not post screenshots

I think your main problem is that F1 is wrong.  Fix that first.  By the context, it looks like you should be using either the bi or bi2 symbols instead.  The f symbol is for a linear current dependent current source and requires a voltage source (usually set to zero) in series with the branch you want to be dependent on.  More info here.  Your joule() function is also bad because it tries to reference a current and you're supposed to use the name of the component not the nodes.  e.g. I(Rpf)
